# How can I update Recyclerview with Broadcast Receiver from Service class?

Tags: android

I am working on music player app and I have included the basic functionality like Play, Pause, next and Previous tracks using service class.

Now I want to update my`recyclerview` UI according to the action that user clicks(eg: on the play, there should be an image of the selected element in `recyclerview`).

I thought to use Broadcast Receiver that service class will broadcast on different actions and then `recyclerview` can update according to the broadcast action. But how do I add such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need an in-activity broadcast receiver. Such receivers are registered when your activity is shown and unregistered once it's hidden.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Here update your RecyclerView
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YourService.YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

And in your service, simply send broadcasts:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION);
// put extras in the intent as you wish
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and I want to update recyclerview's content at specific position according to the data received in broadcast receiver. eg. if service sends a "play" String then i want to put image at that position in recyclerview.